# Ошибка при сборке проекта в Visualstudio

Tags: отладка, icon, visual-studio-2019, release-management

Не пойму что произошло. После сборки проекта у меня в папке DEBUG и RELIS лежат файлы   с разными иконками. В папке Debug с новой иконкой а в Relis со старой. Я уже удалял все иконки и делал приложение со стандартной иконкой. Удалял файлы из этих папок и удалял какие- то  файлы Cash в корневой папке программ. Причем если из папки Debug копировать файл на другой комп и переименовать то иконка опять меняется. И причем куда бы я не копировал файл изначально он с новой иконкой, но стоит переименовать или отправить ярлык то иконка меняется. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

введите сюда описание изображения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно почистить кэш операционной системы. Детали [здесь](https://winitpro.ru/index.php/2016/05/24/sbros-povrezhdennogo-kesha-ikonok-v-windows-10/)

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov а на других компах почему так?

Comment: Во что вы переименовываете? Если переименовать в `MyProg.exe` что произойдет с иконкой?

Comment: А вообще посмотрите любым редактором ресурсов, какие именно иконки линкуются в конкретный exe

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov просто название на русском пишу и все. но по-моему очистка кэша икон прокатила. Спасибо. У меня показывает как надо. Но кто себе скинул программу происходит тоже самое старую иконку отображает. Интересный глюк